# How to use -- cross-compiler -- to compile wxwidget

Tags: arm, wxwidgets, cross-compiling

I have tried a lot but not able to find solution to cross compile the wxwidget ussing cross compiler

ignite@ubuntu:~/wxGTK-2.8.12/gtk-build$ sudo ../configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --build= i686-pc-linux --enable-unicode --prefix=/home/ignite/wxGTK_RPI_build^C

Can some one suggest on this link :---
http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=36772&p=149948#p149948

Why the crosss compiler is not used . When i use to give make command on command line... i have even changed the host & build option at the time of configure :?:

Answer (score -1):

Try using pacman -S wxgtk and see if that works.